# Sorting an ArrayList by two different properties

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

So I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` which represents the number of times a certain word has been encountered in a sentence. What I want to do is put all the words in an `ArrayList<String>`, sorted first by the number of times a word has been encountered, and then break ties by alphabetical order. How would I go about doing that? My code looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private HashMap<String, Integer> map;
    public ArrayList<String> Order() {
         ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
         (...)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a custom comparator.  For the comparison method, you'll need to return a negative value if the first argument should be treated as less than the second, 0 if they are equal, and a positive value if the first argument should be treated as greater than the second.

Note that this sorts the ArrayList in descending order according to the integer value

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String>
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> map;

    public CustomComparator(HashMap<String, Integer> comparisonMap)
    {
        map = comparisonMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
    {
        int count1 = map.get(s1);
        int count2 = map.get(s2);

        if (count1 == count2)
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        return count2 - count1;
    }
}
```

**Two steps to create and sort the ArrayList:**

First, add every key from the HashMap to the ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(map.size());
result.addAll(map.keySet());
```

Then, sort the ArrayList using the custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(result, new CustomComparator(map));
```